# Custom query for custom post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, query, get-posts

I need to display a list of current tasks. Each task has a custom post_type and a start date and end date.

Can someone tell me how to modify my query so it will pick up any tasks that have a start date in the past and an end date in the future? (There's another meta_key named 'end_date')

Here's my query:

```
$todays_date = time();

$args = array ('post_type'      => 'tasks',
               'meta_key'       => 'start_date',
               'meta_compare'   => '>',
               'meta_value'     => $todays_date,
               'orderby'        => 'meta_value'
              );

$tasks = get_posts($args);
```

The problem with the query above is that it's showing tasks that in the future, but haven't started yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your query a bit:

```
$todays_date = time();

$args = array ('post_type'      => 'tasks',
               'meta_key'       => ''end_date,
               'meta_compare'   => '<',
               'meta_value'     => $todays_date,
               'orderby'        => 'meta_value'
              );

$tasks = get_posts($args);
```

and then for each one of this posts get the start_date meta and compare with $today something like:

```
$today = strtotime($today);
foreach ($tasks as $task_post){
  $start = strtotime(get_post_meta($task_post->ID, start_date, true));
  if ($today > $start){
    //to task stuff here
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @בניית אתרים: I can't seem to get it to work. I noticed you had a typo -- strtorime instead of strtotime. I tried to edit your post but it said I didn't change enough characters or something lol. Did you mean $today = strtorime($todays_date); ($todays_date instead of $today)? Not sure if this is the problem, but the way the start_date is stored in my database appears like "1292549400", which is February 3, 2011 at 12:00 AM CST.

Comment: I fixed it. As for your start_date is already stored as integer then you can skip the strtotime. Any way when I'll get home i will look at it again.

Comment: @בניית אתרים No worries. I got it working. Thanks for your help!